# Where are this river and bridge separating two towns, surrounded by mountains?

Tags: identify-this, norway

I think this was taken in Norway.

[image]

Comment: While already answered, I think this question is well below the standards we have come to expect for photo questions. No extra details beyond a possible country.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it does not show any research, does not tell why OP seeks the information and does not have any details beyond a possible country.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This appears to be the [Sykkylven Bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sykkylven_Bridge):

> The Sykkylven Bridge (Norwegian: Sykkylvsbrua) is a concrete bridge that crosses the Sykkylvsfjorden in Sykkylven Municipality in Møre og Romsdal county, Norway. It connects the municipal center of Aure with the village of Ikornnes on the other side of the fjord.

Here is a Google Earth view similar to your picture:

[image]

I found this by using [Google Image Search](https://images.google.com) and pasting in the URL of your picture.

Comment: thanks. I actually put this into Google Image Search, but Google couldn't ID this pic. strange.